# Getting 403 error when loading smart lock

Tags: google-identity

I'm implementing One-tap sign-up in an AngularJS site. It was working fine, but since 1 or 2 weeks ago, I started receiving a 403 error when the smartlock loads (`https://smartlock.google.com/iframe/request?client...`). After that, I get OpenYoloError with the message: "requestTimeout: The API request timed out."

I get this error in localhost and QA, in PROD environment it is working fine. Any ideas?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

I have experienced the same problem. Unfourtunately, after searching around, it appears Google has restricted public access to the API.

> This API is not yet generally available for production use. To join the waiting list, complete the [request form](https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/1FAIpQLSdJkBth-e-62wQ7eYNy12rWOhYBMACChmC_w_CiwbzmcgEGDw/viewform). While your request is being reviewed, you can try the API by running your app on localhost.

https://developers.google.com/identity/one-tap/web/overview